# strange behaviour of str_replace in php

Tags: php, str-replace

```
href=" <?php 
$zzz_stylesheet = "http://127.0.0.1/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css"; 
echo str_replace(".css","-mytheme.css",$zzz_stylesheet);
?>
```

works but

```
href=" <?php 
$zzz_stylesheet = bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); 
echo str_replace(".css","-mytheme.css",$zzz_stylesheet);
?>
```

does not work. Why?
bloginfo is a function in Wordpress which returns the value I have used in first code line.

Comment: If you do an echo $zzz_stylesheet in the second case, does it show the correct info from bloginfo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wordpress’ documentation to `bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/bloginfo):

> Displays information about your blog […] **This always prints a result to the browser.** If you need the values for use in PHP, use `get_bloginfo()`.

*(emphasis added)*

So: Use [`get_bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space after the href="

Do you know about that. If you remove it, then your code, providing that bloginfo() works as expected should work.